# UPBGE 0.3 Saving file in VScode doesn't reflect the blender project anymore

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, game-engine

I've been developing a game in UPBGE for a while now using Components and everything has been okay. Until I managed to change something that is really annoying. Typically I code in VSCODE and save my files there then I run my game and all is well... except now when I run my Game I realized my files are only saved in VScode and not in Blender, at least when I run my code it doesn't reflect my changes.

I have to manually go into the text editor and save the file there as well, by updating it to reflect the changes made in VCcode in order to see my changes in game. This was not so before, does anyone know what I'm missing or went wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: "_I have to manually go into the text editor and save the file there as well_" What text editor? VS Code? I thought you said you already saved it there?

Comment: I'll update the question. But inside of Blender (UPBGE) exists an text editor, a simple IDE. Typically I don't need to mess with that but recently I changed something and now requires me to save there and not in VScode as before.

Comment: what if you just don't open the file in that Blender text editor? Is that possible?

Comment: Not really, from what I understand it gets created there when you first make a "Component" class. Internally only. (meaning the python file is actually inside the .blender file) But after saving the file externally which needs to be done through that blender IDE I typically don't need to touch it again.

Comment: does this happen no matter what UPBGE-external program you use to edit the file externally?

Comment: Do you try to use [this blender extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JacquesLucke.blender-development) in vscode?

Comment: @starball yes, it's the process for creating a Component in UPBGE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after I shutdown the computer and went to bed, the next morning when I turned on my computer it was all working again as usual. I realized that maybe there is some cache issue or something I don't understand but rebooting the computer fixed it.

That's the best answer I have for my issue.